# React router not render appropriate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such structure of routes

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route name="Dashboard" path="/" component={App}>   
        <Route name='Not found' path="*" component={NotFound}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

When i work on /admin/product page, child component not working. I wrote "bicycle" in my opinion. In render function i wrote such code:

```
render() {
   return (
       { this.props.children ? this.props.children : <My component /> }
   );
}
```

I am stuck on /admin/product/:id/edit. When i update my form, component fully rerender and i cant use `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`. I tried to debbug, but my code doesn't go in this methods.

Question is how i can work in child components and use `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the docs.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md

There is such an example like this:

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

URL: `/inbox/messages/:id`

Components: `App -> Inbox -> Message`

So, in your case, child component's url is `/admin/offers/admin/offer/:id/edit`.